# Unity: When parenting cloned object, it instantly unparents

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to clone a object and set it as child of another object using the following code:

```
spawnClone = Instantiate(other.gameObject, position, rotation, plate.transform) as GameObject;
Destroy(spawnClone.GetComponent<Collider>());
//spawnClone.transform.SetParent(plate.transform);
spawnClone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
spawnClone.SetActive(true);
```

Unfortunatly the parenting doesn't work and the cloned object is just placed in the root of the scene. If I try to just move the clone object into any other object in the hierarchy, it just gets out of it again right away (while playing).

Is there anything im doing wrong or that I don't see?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** For a better understanding

I have a gameobject (plate) that has a child object(trigger). The trigger has a mesh collider (trigger enabled) and a script. The script has the following OnTriggerEnter-Method:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (burgerGameManager.gameElement.Contains(other.gameObject.tag)) {
        burgerGameManager.addToPlayerOrder(other.gameObject);
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        Vector3 position;
        if (transform.childCount > 1) {
            Transform lastChild = transform.GetChild(transform.childCount - 1);
            position = lastChild.position;
        } else {
            position = plate.transform.position;
            position.y = position.y + plate.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.size.y;
        }

        spawnClone = Instantiate(other.gameObject, position, other.gameObject.transform.rotation, gameObject.transform) as GameObject;
        Destroy(spawnClone.GetComponent<Collider>());
        //spawnClone.transform.SetParent(plate.transform);
        spawnClone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        spawnClone.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

This method is supposed to trigger when the player drops a object above the plate. That object should hide and spawn a clone of it to appear on the plate.

Later on that script is supposed to be attached to the spawned clone aswell, so that the player can stack objects on the plate. But I did not yet come to that since I didn't even get the first step working as we can see...

Comment: Sounds like some other code is affecting the parenting .. I don't see why your code should behave the way you describe ...

Comment: Your set parent is commented out.

Comment: @BugFinder I've set the parent as 4th parameter in the Instantiate method.

Answer (score 1):

```
spawnClone.transform.parent = plate.transform;
```

Should do it, if the plate is supposed to be the parent

**Edit**

I've recreated your code as follows

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour{
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Vector2 position;
    other.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    position = this.gameObject.transform.position;
    position.y += 0.5f;

    if (transform.childCount >= 1)
    {
        Transform lastChild = transform.GetChild(transform.childCount - 1);
        position = lastChild.transform.position;
        position.y += 0.5f;
    }

    GameObject spawnClone = Instantiate(other.gameObject, position, Quaternion.identity);
    Destroy(spawnClone.GetComponent<Collider2D>());
    spawnClone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
    spawnClone.transform.parent = this.gameObject.transform;
    spawnClone.SetActive(true);
}
```

}

And I got this behaviour, which is what I think you want

[image: sample]

My only conclusion here is that

```
burgerGameManager.addToPlayerOrder(other.gameObject);
```

may be messing with the parenting. Maybe try moving this at the end of the function and see what happens?

Comment: Unfortunatly still not working, but yes the plate is supposed to be the parent.

Comment: Can you edit your post and show any other code that is tied to the behaviour? I ran a quick test and it worked fine for me. From your "it just gets out of it again right away (while playing)." there might be a function that is removing the parent

Comment: I edited my question. If something is still unclear, let me know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: AddToPlayerOrder basically just adds some strings to a dictionary, so it shouldn't be the cause. But at least I now know that the trigger function doesn't seem to be the problem. Guess I'll continue searching then. Thanks for your support!

Comment: I'm sure you'll get it resolved, good luck!